# 既存のprotocolにデフォルト実装(override)を行いたい

Tags: swift

既存のprotocol(`URLSessionDataDelegate`)にデフォルト実装(override)を行いたいのですが、無視されてしまいます。

目的としては`streamManager(didReceive)`は必ず実装しなければいけないようにしてこの`streamManager(didReceive)`を`urlSession(_:dataTask:didReceive)`内で呼ぶようにしたいです。

```swift
public protocol StreamManagerDelegate: URLSessionDataDelegate {
  func streamManager(didReceive data: Data)
}

extension StreamManagerDelegate {
  func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                  dataTask: URLSessionDataTask,
                  didReceive data: Data) {
    streamManager(didReceive: data)
  }
}

class Stream: NSObject, StreamManagerDelegate {
  func streamManager(didReceive data: Data) {
    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
  }
  
  func start() {
     let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
     let session: URLSession = .init(configuration: config,
                                     delegate: self,
                                     delegateQueue: nil)
  }
}
```

自作のコードではうまく動くのですが、上のコードだとデフォルト実装が反映されないです。

```swift
protocol SomeTaskDelegate {
  func someTask(didRecieve data: String)
}

struct SomeTask {
  let delegate: SomeTaskDelegate
}

protocol CustomTaskDelegate: SomeTaskDelegate {
  func printData(_ value: String)
}

extension CustomTaskDelegate {
  func someTask(didRecieve data: String) {
    printData(data)
  }
}

struct main: CustomTaskDelegate {
  func printData(_ value: String) {
    print(value + value)
  }
  
  var value: SomeTask!
  
  init() {
    self.value = SomeTask(delegate: self)
  }
}


main().value.delegate.someTask(didRecieve: "1000")
```

Comment: 考えられる原因として`urlSession(_:dataTask:didReceive)`が`optional`な`@objc`な関数だから出来ないのかもしれません。

Comment: `Non-'@objc' method 'urlSession(_:dataTask:didReceive:)' does not satisfy optional requirement of '@objc' protocol 'URLSessionDataDelegate'`という警告が問題だと思うのですが、解消方法がわかりません。

Answer (score 1):

Swiftで既にCloseされた問題のようです。`Won't Do`としているので、おそらく修正されないのでしょう。

`URLSessionDataDelegate`がSwiftで書かれる日が来ればこの方法が実現可能になると思います。

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3349